# Add multiple menu pages Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to add more than one menu page to my WP site. I can add one page no problem, but when I try to add a second one, it only displays one of the menu pages. I only recently started messing around with plugin creation, but I'm not really sure why I can't get two different menu pages to show up.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'page1_plugin_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'page2_plugin_menu' );

add_menu_page( 'Page One', 'Page One', 'manage_options', 'page_one_slug', 'page_one_function', 'dashicons-admin-post', '' );
add_menu_page( 'Page Two', 'Page Two', 'manage_options', 'page_two_slug', 'page_two_function', 'dashicons-admin-post', '' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try omitting the very last parameter. You're passing an empty string where it should be an integer if passed. For example:

```
add_menu_page( 'Page One', 'Page One', 'manage_options', 'page_one_slug', 'page_one_function', 'dashicons-admin-post' );
add_menu_page( 'Page Two', 'Page Two', 'manage_options', 'page_two_slug', 'page_two_function', 'dashicons-admin-post' );
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Can't believe it was that easy. Wordpress says that last part is for menu position. Once I removed it both pages showed up...odd /shrug

Comment: I think WordPress baulked at the empty string. It was expecting an integer.